# Discovering all Riak nodes from a known node?

Tags: riak

If I know one the IP address of one Riak node, how do I use the Riak API to discover the other nodes?

Update 2013-10-22 5:37 PM CST: One of the reasons I want to do this is to detect network partitions. Being aware of them could be helpful. If my dev-ops infrastructure knows the list of Riak machines, then I could (as needed) contact each node and make sure that all are connected. If not, then it tells me that something in the dev-ops code isn't quite right or something else went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect to `http://my-riak-node:8098/stats` and inspect `ring_members`, which contains the "list of nodes which are members of the ring" according to the [Riak HTTP API](http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/dev/references/http/status/).

Comment: Just as an FYI this ... may not work (where "may" is really "probably"). It's dependent on what is in the node's config which means you get the node name, not necessarily an actual IP address. It's something we're working on (node discovery features) but are still a ways off.

Comment: @BrianRoach Thanks. I'll be happy to +1 a feature request. Is this it? https://github.com/basho/riak/issues/356